# Probemas con conexión a base de datos MySQL Local

Tags: mysql

tengo una aplicación en xojo que me funcionaba perfecto en linux con base de datos local MySql.

Ahora la he tenido que instalar en un Windows X. He instalado MySql + Workbench y paso la base de datos de Linux. Todo ok.

El problema es que la aplicación no conecta con el serividor local MySQL. Pero si lo hace con el mismo usuario y contraseña workbench y Valentina Studio.

Si a mi aplicación le pongo (en el archivo de configuración), una base de datos que tengo en un servidor de internet si conecta. Pero no en la local.

He abierto el puerto 3306 por si acaso en el cortafuegos.

¿ alguna idea de qué puede ser ?
Agrego:

Lenguaje usado el propio de Xojo (real basic).

```
me.Host = thost
me.UserName = tusr
me.Password = tpas
me.DatabaseName = tdb
me.Port = 3306

me.pcon = me.Connect
```

Información de Netstat:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:33060          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49670          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27275        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.1.108:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:33060             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49664             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49665             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49666             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49667             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49668             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49670             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:27275            [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje está desarrollada tu aplicación? ¿Es la misma aplicación que corrías antes pero únicamente has cambiado que en vez de ir a la máquina Linux ahora vaya a la Windows? ¿Podrías compartir un `netstat -an | find "LISTENING"`?

Comment: como estás indicando la ruta al servidor local?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Muéstranos qué has intentado, cómo estás haciendo tu conexión?. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: zerocool, la indico agregando a cada propiedad su valor host, user, etc.

Comment: OscarGarcia esto arroja el netstat con el puerto 3306:
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:33060          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:33060             [::]:0                 LISTENING

Comment: Cecilior, deberías agregar la información adicional mediante [editando tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/327244/edit). En los comentarios se rompe el diseño y no se ve la separación entre líneas. Te hice otras preguntas más, ¿podrías responderlas todas? (lenguaje usado, si es la misma aplicación u otra diferente, los cambios que has realizado para cambiar el uso de un servidor por otro, etc).

Comment: Gracias por agregar información. Veo que en el archivo de configuración, en el apartado `me.Host` has puesto `thost`, ¿es el nombre del servidor donde tienes MySQL en Windows? ¿El programa lo ejecutas desde un equipo remoto? ¿Resuelve ese equipo remoto ese nombre a IP (usa `nslookup thost`)? ¿Qué mensaje de error da tu aplicación?

Comment: thost es una variable donde se guarda la información del host, igual las demás variables de usuario, etc. Se leen de un archivo de configuración. Pero ha puesto todo a manos del tipo me.host = "localhost" y pasa lomismo. igual resto de variables. Todo es en local, mysql instalado en local.

Comment: ¡ Solucionado ! El problema estaba en la forma de autentificar con caching_sha2. he puesto el modo estandar de Mysql y ya conecta bien. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Entonces no eran la misma versión de MySQL, era una versión superior. Has pasado de una 5.x a una 8.x, ¿verdad? Tenías que haber empezado por ahí y por el mensaje de error que te estaba dando :(